# Trying to create a json class in my application

Tags: android, json, class

I try to build a json class to my application and i dont know why it isn't working:
http://pastebin.com/A9Wr9v0m

I need help! Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to use this class on your UI Thread?

if so then the reason it is not working is because you cannot do network actions on the main ui thread they need to be done in either an async class or just a separate thread

Comment: i am trying to make a game, and in the start i want to make a login page.

Comment: android does not allow you to make any HTTP requests on the user interface thread you need to do it in a background thread or in a async class. so the HTTP requests you are making in you json class must be put into a new thread

Comment: You have example? english isn't my first language, so it's better for me to see an example code.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html that webpage has a good example of using async to make a http call

Answer (score 0):

use following code :-

```
  public static String getJsonData(String webServiceName,String parameter)
{  
    try  
    {

    String urlFinal=SERVICE_URI+"/"+webServiceName+"?parameter=";
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(urlFinal.trim()+""+URLEncoder.encode(parameter,"UTF-8"));
    postMethod.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    postMethod.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpResponse response = hc.execute(postMethod);
    Log.i("response", ""+response.toString());
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    final String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    string=responseText;
    Log.i("Output", ""+responseText);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

       return string;
      }
```